# How to make a button press into a gear spinning using a rack without gear turning back?

Tags: gears

I need to have a rack attached to a button that when it gets pressed down, it spins a pinion. The rack then moves up with the button. The problem is that the gear will spin one way when the button is pressed down, then the other way when the button pops up. How can I make the rack come off of the pinion or have the pinion not spin as the button comes up so the gear only spins one way? I also need only a very simple solution. The only problem is a ratchet mechanism would work, as it does not allow the button to come back up.

Comment: `make the rack come off of the pinion` ... that may not be the only solution for one-way rotation ... perhaps ask about the rotation, not about rack disengaging

Comment: Look at the mechanism inside a clicky pen.

Comment: ratchett mechanism then?