# What's the easiest way to rotate a gear on a button press?

Tags: gears

I need an extremely simple design for a mechanism that rotates a gear when a button is pressed, probably using a rack, but the gear cannot spin back while the button comes back up. I've tried using a clicky pen mechanism, but the design is on the too complicated side. Is there an easy way to stop the gear from turning back as the button rises?

Comment: See https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/56359/10902

Comment: This is a duplicate of your previous question. Please don't do that. Edit your previous question to improve it and delete this one.